# Is it a bad practice to refer state in redux reducer directly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

my code is too complex and i found it would be a very complex question with code but my idea of my question is simple:

Is it bad practice to do something like that in redux reducer, referring the state directly and replace the old value with new one

```
case 'something':
const newVal = state.field.map(code here);
state.field = newVal;

return {
  ...state,
}
```

I know it is better doing this:

```
case 'something':
const newVal = state.field.map(code here);

return {
  ...state,
  field: newVal
}
```

But my question is just to know whether the first code is good or bad or normal practice, cause i watched them doing this in some youtube videos which made me wonder?
I know about the power of time travel of redux and i think this remove this power so i think it is a bad practice, or not??

Comment: Yes. State should be immutable. You may see skipped re-renders if you do this

Comment: skipped rerenders?..how this happens?? @BrianThompson

Comment: By doing what you're doing.

Comment: Well the reason I say "may" is because you're spreading state into a new object after mutating it, so it may pick up the change since `prevState !== nextState`. But regardless of that, it's still a bad practice. The reason you might see skipped re-renders is because the need for a re-render is determined by comparing old with new state. Mutating the old state to create the new one would mess up that check for changes, and cause it to think they're the same. The exception would be if you're using immer or some other library that allows safe mutable syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A Redux reducer **must *never* mutate the actual state**](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state).

However, [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) uses the Immer library internally to let you write "mutating" update logic that is converted into a safe and correct immutable update.  We specifically recommend that you should use Redux Toolkit as the default way to write Redux logic.